# Calculating the orthogonal vector of a line inside a plane

Tags: vector-spaces

Writing a computer graphics related program, I cant figure out how to solve the following problem:

**In a 3D space, I have given:**

- 3 distinct points, that describe a plane.
- 2 of those points describe a line (inside the plane).

**I am now looking for:**

- The vector that is orthogonal to the line, and also lies inside the plane.

As I use the resulting vector as the rotation axis of a quaternion rotation, the direction (positive/negative) or length doesnt matter. How can I calculate this vector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cross product.  If your points are $A, B$, and $C$ and you want a vector in the plane of these three perpendicular to $AB$, you can use $d = AB \times AC$ to be a vector perpendicular to both.  Then $e=AB \times d$ will be in the plane (as it is perpendicular to $d$) and perpendicular to $AB$.  Did you want to require that $e$ go through $C$ as well?

Comment: Great, that was what I was looking for! No, it doesnt have to go through C. As I said I will be using *e* as a rotation axis. The point to rotate around will be A then, but that is something the framework does for me :). Thanks again!

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier:  Glad to help.  I now recall there is an identity that may help, found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product that $a\times (a \times b)=a (b \cdot a) - b (a \cdot a)$ which may make it cleaner